# Turn off system restore via the command line in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, system-restore

I'm trying to turn off system restore via the command line.

This is the command I'm using:

```
Reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore" /V DisableSR /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Then I run it as an administrator, and it says that the command completed successfully, but when I go to *Computer* -> *Properties* -> *System Protection* it still shows that system restore is on for the drive.

Is there an additional step or a different command?

Comment: "Is there an additional step?"  Yes, reboot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from PowerShell (run as Administrator):

```
disable-computerrestore -drive "C:\"
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347710.aspx

Comment: `srservice` doesn't exist in Windows Vista and later.

Comment: I treid that and got "disable-computerrestore is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @user214577 in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), not cmd!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that System restore uses the volume shadowing service.  So if you want to totally disable this functionality, first disable the volume shadowing service.  Then there are commands to manipulate the number of snapshots present on a system and delete them or even disable the functionality.  Sorry I don't remember them off hand but check the microsoft site to get the commands used to manipulate the snapshot functionality.

Comment: this deletes all of the shadow copies.
vssadmin delete shadows /all /quiet

Answer (score 0):

I to have been struggling to find out how to disable system protection in Windows 7 via command line.  What I've found out matches to what MDPC stated.

To turn off the Volumn Shadow copy via command prompt: `sc config vss start= disabled`

Then stop the service with: `net stop vss`

If you're looking to manipulate the restore points then you need to use the vssadmin commands:

`vssadmin list shadowstorage` - This command lists all connected hard drives and their used, allocated and maximum shadow copy storage space.

`vssadmin list shadows` - This command lists all existing shadow copies on the system

`vssadmin delete shadows /for=c: /oldest` - This command deletes the oldest shadow copy on drive C

`vssadmin delete shadows /for=d: /all` - This command deletes all existing shadow copies on drive D

`vssadmin delete shadows /for=c: /shadow=ID` - Deletes the selected shadow copy. The IDs are listed when you use the list shadows command.

`vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=c: /maxsize=2GB` - Sets the shadow storage for drive C to 2 Gigabyte. May delete existing restore points starting with the oldest if space is not sufficient to store all System Restore points

(I think the original is from [WayBack](https://web.archive.org/web/20181110091034/https://www.ghacks.net/2012/10/05/manage-system-restore-from-the-command-line/) [Manage System Restore from the command line - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2012/10/05/manage-system-restore-from-the-command-line/))