# Empty drives show 2 GB used, Explorer shows nothing

Tags: windows, disk-space

I have 4 drives in Windows: C:, D:, E: and F:. Except C:, all of them are empty.

[image: Drive List and Size]

Suddenly it shows up to 2 GB space used – even when there are no files.

[image: Contents in Drive]

[[image: Viewing hidden files and folders through cmd admin]]

When I format the drives, it's fine for a while until it shows used space again.

I use Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit.

Comment: Did you enable the option to view system and hidden files?

Comment: yes i have enabled the option to view hidden files

Comment: Just to be sure, you enable to view system files too, right?

Comment: yes i have enabled it from folder options in control panel

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Explorer's "Computer" view to illustrate the issue.

Comment: There's no such thing as a NTFS file system that has "no files".

Comment: Nikhil, please confirm that you have **BOTH** as in the **TWO** options set appropriate in the **Folder Options --> View** tab options of **Windows\File Explorer**.  As mentioned by Julie 2 days ago, ensure BOTH settings are set to ***show BOTH*** **hidden and system files**. **Show Hidden** needs *selected* whereas **Hide Protected** should NOT be **selected** so *unchecked*... please confirm this with 100% certainty.

Comment: Please paste the output of "dir /ahs" (run in an admin cmd window) from one (or more) of the affected drives.  I suspect you'll find pagefile.sys or hiberfil.sys on those drives.  Adding up to 2GB per disk.

Comment: @Xalorous i have pasted the output of  "dir /ahs" command above

Comment: @Xalorous Now even the total free space is also showing wrong

Comment: try the ntfs metadata tool from sysinternals that I posted. maybe the metadata grow so much

Comment: You should add info, what those disks are, partitions on some particular physical drive? `diskmgmt.msc` screenshot + exact type of your HDD.

Comment: Now that we see that there is indeed something there, list the contents of `$RECYCLE.BIN` and `System Volume Information`.  Doing a right click from `Windows Explorer` to get the properties would be the best way to get their size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I doubt that those Windows disks are physical drives, I guess from their size that they are partitions, so you have partitioned your disk and now you probably find a bit disappointing that it takes some extra space of your drive.

Run command line as administrator and then:

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage /on=D:
vssadmin list shadowstorage /on=E:
vssadmin list shadowstorage /on=F:
```

It will show how much space did **Windows Shadow Copy Storage** take. See those articles for more detail:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5482/make-system-restore-use-less-space-in-windows-7/
http://www.howtogeek.com/123268/windows-hard-drive-wrong-capacity/

You can turn off shadow copy by writing in elevated command prompt:

```
powershell
```

which starts a powershell prompt and then:

```
disable-computerrestore -drive "D:\"
disable-computerrestore -drive "E:\"
disable-computerrestore -drive "F:\"
```

Here is a link to [technet manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347710.aspx) and also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/774222/285900).

Comment: Wouldn’t the correct command be `vssadmin list shadows`? // edit: Nevermind, I guess `shadowstorage` shows disk space used by shadow copies?

Comment: @DanielB Yes...

Comment: @DanielB windows commandline commands sometimes use autocompletion for non-ambiguous options.  It could be that the command you suggested `vssadmin list shadows` is actually interpreted as the full command `vssadmin list shadowstorage`

Comment: It isn't. It lists shadow copies, but doesn't show how much space they reference.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Thank you.. With your help finally i found the problem and it's solution.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Selecting all files and viewing their properties skips files that your user account doesn't have **access to** while viewing the disk properties reads the NTFS meta data and always shows the correct usage.

Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) ([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token)) to see a better view of the disk space usage. Running it as admin shows hidden folders such as `System Volume Information` where system restore points and chkdsk logs are stored.

[image]

[image]

if this doesn't show the usage, it could be that the NTFS metadata/Master File Table (MFT) have grown. Run the tool ntfsinfo.exe  to see the size of the NTFS metedata. On my drive the MFT is over 600MB:

```
NtfsInfo v1.2 - NTFS Information Dump
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Volume Size
-----------
Volume size            : 457876 MB
Total sectors          : 937730949
Total clusters         : 117216368
Free clusters          : 47031672
Free space             : 183717 MB (40% of drive)

Allocation Size
----------------
Bytes per sector       : 512
Bytes per cluster      : 4096
Bytes per MFT record   : 0
Clusters per MFT record: 0

MFT Information
---------------
MFT size               : 677 MB (0% of drive)
MFT start cluster      : 786432
MFT zone clusters      : 13913408 - 13933696
MFT zone size          : 79 MB (0% of drive)
MFT mirror start       : 2

Meta-Data files
---------------
```

This could cause your hidden usage.

Comment: I like your answer and sure hope OP will validate it.

Comment: No, I have tried this its showing exact files and size ... NO description of that 2gb space

Comment: @NikhilKrishnan You did start is as Admin, right?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes

Comment: maybe the NTFS metadata grow too much: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897424 look at the size that this sysinternals tool show you

Comment: All those theories (including the mine) are only wild guesses. How could possibly anything like recycle bin, restore point or MFT table grow by itself by 2 GB on a newly formatted disk? Running `ntfsinfo` is a good idea, but it looks to me like something less obvious like a disk firmware problem or a virus.

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to show hidden files in the Explorer window to see all the files.  There remain the protected operating system files that will not appear, such as the pagefile.sys and hibernation files.  I suspect your 2 GB is taken up by a page file, but here is how you may know, for sure.

1. The first procedure is recommended because it doesn't change any settings and can be done at any time, regardless of your Explorer's view settings.

   - Open a command prompt (Win+r ▶ cmd)
   - List all hidden files in the root of the **C:** drive by typing `dir /ah c:\` then hit *Enter*.
   - If there is a page and/or hibernation file, you'll see it, now.
2. The second procedure does change your Explorer's view settings, which you're already familiar with, and it's recommended to change the settings back after you find the files you're looking for.

   - In an *Explorer* window, click **Tools** ▶ **Folder Options...**
   - Select the **View** tab
   - Clear the check box next to *Hide protected operating system files*, then click *OK*.
   - Most files -- the ones likely using up space -- will now be visible in the *Explorer* window.

Comment: I also suspect the pagefile is the culprit.  If so, and also assuming these are partitions on one physical disk, this practice results in reduced performance and gains nothing.  It's ok to have multiple pagefiles on multiple physical disks, this can increase performance.  But multiple pagefiles on one physical disk (implies/requires multiple partitions) does not provide any performance increase, and it does increase complexity, and therefore increases likelihood for something to break.

Answer (score 1):

On all of my hard drives (I have three) I have two hidden folders. these are $RECYCLE.BIN and System Volume Information.

You can see the file size of the recycle bin, but not sysvol as it is system protected. If you were to boot into safe mode as the local admin, you may find that system volume does infact have files in it taking up space.

System volume information is used for restore points.

As Julie has pointed out, if you enable view system and hidden files, you will see these two folders.

Comment: Since OP replied that it is enabled, this would make your answer wrong (although I still have my doubts too).

Comment: "Windows stores restore-point files in a hidden folder named "System Volume Information" on the root of every drive, partition or volume, including most external drives and some USB flash drives." From microsoft press

Comment: Well that's of course a lie :D, they aren't *stored* in the folder (not anymore, anyway). It just contains a link to the shadow copy. System Restore isn't enabled on non-system drives by default.

Comment: So as the other answer shows, other things are stored in SVI, not just system restore. But OP would have to run that utility to show exacly what it is. Suffice to say it is windows related.